# Dimension of $B(H)/K(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space. I'm looking for an easy way to show that the dimension of the quotientalgebra $B(H)/K(H)$ is infinite.

Attempt:

If the dimension is finite, the quotient is separable. Also $K(H)$ is separable, so we get that $B(H)$ is separable, which is not the case.

(1) Is my argument correct?

(2) Are there other easy ways to see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument seems correct, but I believe there are details to be filled out to conclude that $B(H)$ is separable.

A fun way to see this (but an overkill): if $B(H)/K(H)$ is finite dimensional, then it is a nuclear $C^*$-algebra. Since $K(H)$ is also nuclear and we have a short-exact sequence of $C^*$-algebras
$$0\to K(H)\to B(H)\to B(H)/K(H)\to0 $$
we have that $B(H)$ is nuclear, which is not the case, since $H$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with nuclearity but I'm soon getting there.